# Показать/Скрыть блок jQuery

Tags: jquery

Всем привет!

Подскажите как в [таком варианте](http://jsfiddle.net/WQ7r9/) менять текст самой ссылки? Или посоветуйте другой вариант.

HTML:

```
<a class="show-block" href="#block">Показать всех</a>
<div id="block">Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

CSS:

```
#block {
    display: none;
    width: 600px;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.show-block").click(function() {
        $($(this).attr('href')).toggle('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно сохранить альтернативный текст и показывать вот так:

HTML:

```
<a class="show-block" href="#block" data-alt="Скрыть всех">Показать всех</a>
<div id="block">Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.show-block").click(function() {  
        var $t=$(this),alt=$t.data('alt');
        $t.data('alt',$t.text());$t.text(alt);          
        $($t.attr('href')).stop().toggle('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```